# Android: How to refresh a tablelayout after removing a row?

Tags: java, android, refresh, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a tablelayout that retrieves data from a *.txt file.
For every line of data in the txt file, there will be one row of data.

Let's say I have two rows of data in the txt file right now, it makes sense that two tablerows will be generated.

Then, I added a OnLongPressListener which, when called, will delete one row of data from the txt file.

Now's the first question: After deleting data in the txt file, how do I refresh my tablelayout to reflect that change?

Second question is: After I get my first question solved, is it possible to have some kind of animation where one row will fade out or slide out instead of just disappearing outright?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to accept answers that worked for you so that next time you ask questions - people don't hesitate to post answers!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are still looking for answer. But I came across this post facing kinda the same problem. Plus the fact that I was forced to use `TableLayout` (the amount of code written using `TableLayout` is huge and it wasn't my call to switch to `ListView`).
What I ended up doing was to remove all the views from `TableLayout` using:

```
`tableLayout.removeAllViews();`
```

But that's not gonna work if the number of rows after removal changes drastically. I needed to invalidate my view too, using a handler. Here is the rest of my code.

```
protected static final int REFRESH = 0;

private Handler _hRedraw;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tree_view_activity);

    _hRedraw=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case REFRESH:
                redrawEverything();
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    ...
}
private void redrawEverything()
{
    tableLayout.invalidate();
    tableLayout.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

There is only one part left and that's the part where you send a message to your handler to refresh your view. Here is the code for it:

```
_hRedraw.sendEmptyMessage(REFRESH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `ListView` instead? It gives you better control when using an MVC model where there's a dataset tied to a `View`. So you could have a class that extends `BaseAdapter`. This class binds your data to the `View` and this  class also has a method: `notifyDataSetChanged()` which is what should solve your problem.

You may find [notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example) and [customListView](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) helpful.

Let me know if you need any help further.

Comment: I agree list is a much better way to go. and a possible animation solution would be easier to find/create.

Comment: Alright I tried your suggestion but it's nearly impossible (or I just don't know how to do it right) to convert my setup to listview. What I have is a background picture of a resistor and four textview (each with no text but different background colours). You see how that's working?

I tried applying listview and customizing my own simple_list.xml to have a background of a resistor. But I don't know how to add four textview to one row of listview.

Comment: Okay. I don't know how your four TextViews will appear but row.xml in the tutorial already has two TextViews so you just add two more, shouldn't that be easy?

Comment: Accept the answer that helped you so that answers may know what worked for you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Generally in ***onCreate()*** we do all the stuff that shows the ui with text, try to put the code that makes up UI in a private method ***say setUpTabView()*** and try to call this from onCreate and even try calling this ***setUpTabView()*** when ever the text changed. This kind of approach i did in grid view. worked very well...!